# UILabel not getting set second time programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa, uilabel

I have a timer that with 1 sec interval and a function that calculates a value and sets to a uilabel every 1 sec.

```
-(void)StartCostTimer
{
    Global *global = [Global getInstance];
    global.Timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(SetCost:)
                                           userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:global.Timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:global.Timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

    [global.Timer fire];
}
```

and here is the function to calculate

```
-(void)SetCost:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    Global *global = [Global getInstance];
    double cost,timer_add;

    timer_add = ((double)global.total_interval + / 3600);

    cost = (timer_add * 25);

    [self.label_cost_of_operation setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cost of Operation: $%f",cost]];

    NSLog(@"Time: %f ----- Cost: %@",timer_add, [self.label_cost_of_operation text]);
}
```

Now here is the issue.
When I first run the app and the view appears for 1st time, the code runs properly and label is updated every 1 sec. Now when I go to another screen and come back to this, I can see the timer running and also the log from the function that displays the text that is set in the uilabel.

eg:

```
2014-01-01 18:35:18.407 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.056347 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.408664
2014-01-01 18:35:19.407 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.056625 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.415615
2014-01-01 18:35:20.407 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.056902 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.422554
2014-01-01 18:35:21.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.057180 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.429499
2014-01-01 18:35:22.407 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.057458 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.436448
2014-01-01 18:35:23.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.057735 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.443385
2014-01-01 18:35:24.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.058013 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.450330
2014-01-01 18:35:25.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.058291 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.457278
2014-01-01 18:35:26.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.058569 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.464220
2014-01-01 18:35:27.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.058847 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.471165
2014-01-01 18:35:28.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.059124 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.478106
2014-01-01 18:35:29.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.059402 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.485052
2014-01-01 18:35:30.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.059680 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.492001
2014-01-01 18:35:31.407 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.059958 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.498945
2014-01-01 18:35:32.406 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.060235 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.505884
2014-01-01 18:35:33.405 Truck Sheet[8271:a0b] Time: 0.060513 ----- Cost: Cost of Operation: $1.512831
```

but the label on the iPad is blank (the value that I set in storyboard). How is this possible?
I can see that the value is getting set in UILabel and also the NSLog contains the value from uiLabel not the calculated value. Still I cannot see the label getting updated..!

Comment: i know you are using storyboard but still like to know are you putting any efforts on navigating back to the timer screen.

Comment: yes i am using modal segue and maintaining all the previous data. Actually my timer screen has timers on them. These timers values are also set in labels which work properly when i come back to timer screen. Dont know why this is creating an issue..!!

Comment: on a side note: try sticking to the naming conventions. Methods and variables start lowercase (global.timer instead of global.Timer, -setCost instead of -SetCost etc.) . And method name's *usually* shouldn't be called getSomething (instance or sharedInstance instead of getInstance)

Comment: Nine times out of ten this is because the label pointer is nil.

Comment: @HotLicks: What's the work around? There is no initialization such as in android. But other labels are working, why should this give such behaviour. On the other hand, if you check my code, in the NSlog i have printed the value from the label's text that appears to come, so it is not nil.

Comment: Have you tried dispatching into the main thread?  Timers are usually run in a background thread.  I do see that you add the timer to the main run loop (not sure why you add it to the current run loop too, but that is just my inexperience talking).  Try dispatching into the main thread to make the label text change.

Comment: @Putz1103 i am sorry i dint get you, but there are 5 other labels running with 5 timers with same code and they seen to work fine. I am having problem with this one where the label disappears when this controller is visible for 2nd time onwards.

Comment: Do an NSLog that shows the label's superview.  If the superview is nil then for some reason it's being removed (or not re-added) to the viewcontroller's view.

Comment: There are any number of ways that a label can be hidden.  One thing you could do is put "canned" text into the label in the XIB and make sure that shows up.  If not then check that the label is really in the view and that there is no view over the top of it.  (Sometimes this takes some clever programming to sort out.)

Answer (score 0):

self.label_cost_ofblahblah is almost certainly nil. as in the outlet isn't connected. put in a breakpoint above the line and in the debugger look at selfs variables.

also you should be using cocoa idiom iVar names in camelCase.

if you have a singleton class called Global you are at best doing something against good OOP cocoa paradigm...